# Set TableView Cell image from URL using AFNetworking 3.0 (asynchronous)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking-3

I am trying to figure out how can I set an imageView in my TableViewCell using URL and AFNetworking 3.0 in asynchronous mode.

I don´t know how to work with it properly. Exactly in this line:

```
cell.productImageView.image = image;
```

It doesn´t work. I cannot attribute it directly, right?

Here is my code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

ProductCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"productCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];




NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_URL"]];


[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage * _Nonnull image) {



    cell.productImageView.image = image;



} failure:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    NSLog(@"%@",error);

}];





return cell;
```

}

Comment: what's the issue with your code? Not getting Image? OR unable to pass image on cell's imageview?

Comment: Try with `__weak ProductCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"productCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
`

Comment: @Piyush Patel Thank you!!! It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Piyush Patel !!! It worked, I could load the image on cell´s imageView. Here, what I did:

```
__weak ProductCell *weakCell = cell;
```

`[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage * _Nonnull image) {

    weakCell.productImageView.image = image;

} failure:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    NSLog(@"%@",error);

}];

return cell;`